# nodeJS docker can't connect to redis server

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I have a nodeJS-app dockerized. In this, I use a Redis connection.
Redis is running on localhost 127.0.0.1:6379. **It's not running as a docker container!**

In my nodejs file, I have the following:

```
client = redis.createClient({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
});
```

When I run `node index`, the connection works. But when I build the docker image and run a container, the nodeJS app cannot connect to the redis server (ECONNREFUSED).

I have also tested it with a managed redis server on GCP, it cannot connect either.

**Edit:**

I can now connect to the **localhost** redis client by using the following code in nodeJS:

```
client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'host.docker.internal',
  port: 6379
});
```

But I still can't connect to an external IP-address, like this:

```
client = redis.createClient({
  host: EXTERNAL_IP_HERE,
  port: 6379
});
```

Comment: From within the container, `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) refers to the container itself, not the host. Any reason you're not running the Redis server as a container ? Docker networks are very useful.

Comment: Yes but I'm planning on deploying the docker container on a VM in GCP and I want to use a managed redis server in GCP.

Comment: You could use a dockerized Redis server for local development, this is very common. Does GCP give a public IP address, can you `ping` it from your computer for example ? I never used it but it could be an IP for a private network I guess.

Comment: Yes I can ping it. When I using the code with the external ip and I run ``node index``, it works. But in the docker container I get an "connect ETIMEDOUT" error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I found the solution. I was trying to connect to the INTERAL ip of the redis server through my local setup. An internal IP only works when you upload the code to a google cloud VM. My bad. Thanks anyway for your comments. Have a nice day!

Comment: That's what I was saying by private IP. Thank you, you too !

Answer (score -1):

Run your docker container with [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/):

```
$ docker run --network=host mycontainer
```